# How do i merge two json object in android spinner

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Is it possible to merge both object into a single object after retrieving the data from my database?

Here is my android retrieve code for spinner

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        final List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

     try
            {
                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json, json1;

                s_name = new String[JA.length()];
                s_gender = new String[JA.length()];

                for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
                {
                    json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    s_name[i]=json.getString("s_name");

                }
                for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
                {
                    json1 = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    s_gender[i]=json1.getString("s_gender");
                }

                for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
                {
                    list1.add(s_name[i]);
                }
                for(int i = 0; i<s_gender.length; i++)
                {
                    list1.add(s_gender[i]);
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            spinner_fn();

        }

private void spinner_fn() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
}
```

s_name retrieves sports and s_gender retrieves the gender. In my code it displays the sports name but no gender. What i want is something like this
Basketball Female

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the code is adding all `sport names` values then all `gender` values

1.) Iterate through both arrays in a single loop.

2.) Fetch values from both arrays and add them as single `String` in the list

Combine both arrasy as single string for spinner adapter like this

```
 for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
    {
       list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
       //         Basketball +" "+ Female
    }
```

---

you can further optimize your `JSON Parsing` code with single loop to fetch your both values

```
 for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
     {
        json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
        s_gender[i] =  json.getString("s_gender");
        s_name[i]   =  json.getString("s_name");    
     }
```

---

Code will be

```
class YourActivity extends ..... 
{

    Spinner spinner1;

    // Declare list1 global 
    List<String> list1;

    Somefunction() {
        try
        {
            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);

            // initialize list
            list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json, json1;

            s_name   = new String[JA.length()];
            s_gender = new String[JA.length()];

            for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
            {
                json        = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                s_name[i]   = json.getString("s_name");
                s_gender[i] = json.getString("s_gender");
            }

            for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(s_name[i]+" "+s_gender[i]);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        spinner_fn();
    }

    private void spinner_fn() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Games.this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
        spinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
    }
}
```

Comment: still showing only the sports sir. What should i change here?   ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s_name);

Comment: because when i chance the s_name to the gender. The spinner becomes male and female only

Comment: @osoda  your `list1` must be declared inside your class but outside functions , like the same way your are doing with `spinner1`

Comment: @osoda i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

**Create new class**

```
class SportsModel {
    private String name = "";
    private String gender = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + gender;
    }
}
```

**Now Edit your code with below one.**

```
 try {
        final JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);

        final ArrayList<SportsModel> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
            final SportsModel model = new SportsModel();
            final JSONObject json = JA.getJSONObject(i);

            model.setName(json.getString("s_name"));
            model.setGender(json.getString("s_gender"));

            list1.add(model);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    spinner_fn();
```